# Warning: 'void checkGlError(const char*)' used but never defined

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm compiling a Shared library using Android NDK r6b. All classes are C++.

I have the following two classes:

**Utils.hpp**

```
#ifdef USE_OPENGL_ES_1_1
#include <GLES/gl.h>
#include <GLES/glext.h>
#else
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>
#endif
#include <android/log.h>

// Utility for logging:
#define LOG_TAG    "ROTATEACCEL"
#define LOG(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

static void checkGlError(const char* op);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**Utils.cpp**

```
#include "Utils.hpp"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

static void checkGlError(const char* op) {
    for (GLint error = glGetError(); error; error
            = glGetError()) {
        LOGI("after %s() glError (0x%x)\n", op, error);
    }
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

When I want to use this function in other C++ files I `#include "Utils.hpp"`. But, in those files I get an error:

```
undefined reference to `checkGlError'
```

Why am I getting this warning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've made it `static`. It only lives in that specific translation unit therefore. The solution is to remove the `static` keyword.

The warning is telling you that in the header file you "promised" there would be a definition in that translation unity if one was needed, but one has not been provided and it was needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
static void checkGlError(const char* op);
```

It is a *static* function, that means, it has internal linkage, and therefore cannot be called from *another* translation unit.

Remove the `static` keyword from it's declaration as well as from it's definition, and it would work fine.